# How to use an Index.php in a subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am a complete beginner when it comes to htaccess solutions. I am looking for a solution to use an index.php in a subdirectory. I found this solution, but it adds a " / " to everything.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

1. How to remove the index.php extension ?

> *site.com/en/index.php*
> *site.com/en/*

2. How can I prevent it from adding a "/" to every file ?
   So that the URL is normal again like in the example.

> *site.com/en/test*

Comment: There's nothing abnormal about a `/` at the end of a URL. Is it causing a specific problem?

Comment: The problem is that each additional link creates a folder again ?  So *site.com/en/test.php* works but *site.com/en/test/* does not work. It comes a 404 error.

Comment: The mere existence of URL does not create a physical folder on the disk. But what exactly is the purpose of your rule? You didn't explain really what your overall goal is, it would help to have that context. e.g. `site.com/en/test/ does not work` ...is that the input, or the output? It wasn't clear? And what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: When entering the URL "site.com/en/test/" a 404 error occurs.  The goal was to load the index.php from the directory at the "site.com/en/". But with each further linking it adds a / behind and an error comes.

Comment: So basically you want any URL which begins with `site.com/en/` to redirect to `site.com/en/index.php` regardless of any other content following that in the original URL? Is that correct?